# Cropping image using jquery canvasCrop returning black background on top and bottom of image

Tags: javascript

I am using jquery upload image canvas. While i am uploading an image, resizing and then save,the cropped image background is black. I want to change the black background to white.

Given is the example...[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcLRf.jpg)

```
   getDataURL: function(type){
                    var type = type||"png",
                        width = thumbBox.width,
                        height = thumbBox.height,
                        hiddenCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
                        hiddenContext = hiddenCanvas.getContext("2d");
                    hiddenCanvas.width = width;
                    hiddenCanvas.height = height;
                    hiddenCanvas.width = $(".thumbBox").width();
                    hiddenCanvas.height = $(".thumbBox").height();
    //                hiddenContext.drawImage(visbleCanvas, clipArgument.sx, clipArgument.sy, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
                    hiddenContext.drawImage(visbleCanvas, clipArgument.dx, clipArgument.dy, visbleCanvas.width,visbleCanvas.height);
                    return hiddenCanvas.toDataURL('image/'+type);
                }
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Issue has been resolved.
Just added
hiddenContext.fillStyle = '#FFF';
                hiddenContext.fillRect(0, 0,hiddenCanvas.width,hiddenCanvas.height);
                hiddenContext.strokeStyle = '#eaeaea';
                hiddenContext.lineWidth=5;
                hiddenContext.translate(0.5, 0.5);
                hiddenContext.strokeRect(0, 0,hiddenCanvas.width,hiddenCanvas.height);